# Is there any side effect of changing Text File Encoding to UTF-8 in eclipse?

Tags: java, encoding

I was converting some number into hindi word. I made jar file for that and after import I was getting ???????. After setting to Text File Encoding to UTF-8 it worked. 
What is the side effect for this?

Comment: If you are planning to write Hindi characters to a file, then you should be using an encoding which supports those characters, such as UTF-8.  This is pretty much your only option.

Comment: these are not actually side effects. side effects are effects that can't be foreseen or expected. the fact that certain languages/symbols can't be shown in one encoding, while they were visible in another, is not something that can't be foreseen or expected.

Comment: ya , UTF-8 works perfectly

Comment: You need to have a program which can read UTF-8